# Is decrease in gravitational entropy made up for by gravitational waves?

Tags: gravity, entropy, gravitational-waves

If we look at objects in the universe, they form orderly structures like spheres, planetary systems, galactic spirals, etc. Is this decrease in entropy balanced by a decrease due to gravitational waves appearing during the formation of these structures? So the total of gravitational entropy decreases?

Comment: A lot of heat is produced in other ways. For example the tidal forces that have caused the Moon to move away from the Earth (over millions of years) have generated heat due to changing stresses on rocks that are not perfectly elastic, and viscous energy losses in the oceans.

Comment: From wikipedia article on entropy " Entropy is central to the second law of thermodynamics, which states that the entropy of isolated systems left to spontaneous evolution cannot decrease with time, as they always arrive at a state of thermodynamic equilibrium, where the entropy is highest. " What makes you think that the contribution of gravitation should be separable  abd go against this?

Comment: @Peter So part of the gravitational entropy is conversed in a photon field (instead of GW)?

Comment: @annav Well, doesn't a structure of masses in the form of a spiral (galaxies) possess lower entropy that the masses spread out randomly?

Comment: You have to be careful with entropy in gravity. Without gravity you'd think that the highest entropy state would be for a gas to fill whatever volume it's in. *With* gravity (let's ignore black hole thermodynamics) the highest entropy state is for the matter to clump together and form structures. (if you don't ignore black hole thermodynamics, the highest entropy state is for everything to collapse into a giant black hole, which then radiates away into Hawking radiation). Anyway, the point is, most of your intuition about thermodynamics without gravity doesn't apply when you include gravity.

Comment: @Andrew The maximum entropy of a system of masses does indeed correspond to the event horizon of a black hole with corresponding mass.  The BH is the state for which mass has a maximum entropy. So you would expect that a galaxy with spirals has less entropy than the black hole hole corresponding to it. So when the masses start out randomly in space, is entropy minimal? The space in which they are contained can contain as much entropy as the surface of a BH with that radius could, so more than the entropy of the BH corresponding to the masses. What's the net effect, if you know what I mean?

Comment: @MatterGauge What I'm saying is that, when accounting for gravity, the entropy of a gas of particles with a total mass of $M$ will (a) have some entropy if the mass is initially distributed randomly over some volume (but not "minimal" entropy), (b) have the same or more entropy if the matter collapses into some structures like spiral arms due to gravity, (c) have its maximum entropy when collapsed into a black hole of mass $M$ (modulo Hawking radiation). The Schwarzschild radius of the black hole of mass $M$ will be smaller (probably a lot smaller) than the linear scale of the original volume.